# How can I get the details (properties and/or methods) of object Microsoft.Rtc.Management.ADConnect.Schema.OCSADUser?

Tags: powershell, skype-for-business

Some Camdlets for Skype for Business Online returns objects e.g. Get-CsOnlineUser returns Microsoft.Rtc.Management.ADConnect.Schema.OCSADUser but I haven’t found any place online where this object is described. Someone here knows how to get its documentation that describes its properties/methods?

Comment: Outside of general curiosity. What is it about this type do you feel you is of value? Since it is not publically documented, then there is probably nothing specific which MS felt a need to expose or usable to anyone outside of MS / MS Lync/Skype dev team. Well, that and it's never been directly usable to date.

Comment: MS developed an interface for SfB using WinRM ; what called my attention was I didn´t find a public way to get details about how to interact with the objects returned/sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Get-Member` cmdlet to list the properties and methods of an object.

For your purposes you would use it like so:

```
Get-CsOnlineUser | Get-Member
```

The console will then print out a list of properties and methods.
Additionally you can get the overloads for a method by "running" the method without any given parameters like so:

```
$x.Delete

OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
void Delete()
void Delete(bool recursive)
```

Comment: That statement will returned the number of items coming  from Get-CsOnlineUser cmdlet.

Comment: @albertogurrion I'm not sure what you mean, is it not working for you?

Comment: @albertogurrion Could you explain how it's not working? An example of what you're seeing might help. For example when I run Get-Member against a System.IO.FileInfo object I see this: https://pastebin.com/izHygL7z

Comment: As I said Get-CsOnlineUser | Get-Member returns the items in this case the list of users and NOT the members of Microsoft.Rtc.Management.ADConnect.Schema.ADOCOnlineUser object.

Comment: @albertogurrion I'm confused as to why you are getting the results you are as I cannot replicate them. When I run the commands I get the output of the members for the object as you can see https://pastebin.com/q5DdjVkr Can you list the steps you take to get the results you currently are?

Comment: Thanks Persistent13 before asking here I've try to query the members at "RunTime" using something like $Users=Get-CsOnlineUser -ResultSize 10 | Where-Object {...} (1.keep the result in a var) and then it displays what you said using $Users | Get-Member
So that's ok you found a way, althought what I really wanted to know is if these set of objects are published in a document from microsoft.